# eof of istream in C++

Tags: c++, eof, istream

```
bool ios::eof ( ) const;
```

According to the library,

> The function returns true if the eofbit stream's error flag has been
>   set by a previous i/o operation. This flag is set by all standard
>   input operations when the End Of File is reached in the sequence
>   associated with the stream.

I wrote a program to run some tests:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    float f;
    ifs >> f;

    cout << ifs.eof() << endl; //check if eofbit set

    ifs.close();
}
```

I tested 2 files, testcase1.txt and testcase2.txt.

testcase1.txt was generated in the terminal with `cat`, [Ctrl-D] was used to end input:

```
[~/C++ $] cat > testcase1.txt
1.234[Ctrl-D]
```

testcase2.txt was generated in `vim`, I opened up `vim` and just inputted `1.234`, and then saved and exited.

**Test Result**

Test result with `testcase1.txt` is `1`, which means the `eofbit` is set,

```
[~/C++ $] ./a.out testcase1.txt
1
```

Test result with `testcase2.txt` is `0`,

```
[~/C++ $] ./a.out testcase2.txt
0
```

I open both `testcase1.txt` and `testcase2.txt` in `vim`, they look exactly the same, then why the `eofbit` wasn't set for `testcase2.txt`?

Comment: Could it be that vim appended a newline?

Comment: @Alcott: they may look the same but be slightly different. You could check with an hexadecimal editor for example whether their content is exactly identical... chances are they are not.

Comment: @BjörnPollex, I open both files in `vim`, they all are one line in there, look like no `newline` or `whitespace` appended, just `1.234`.

Comment: @Alcott, the "new line" is a end-of-line marker. You have NL even if you got one line.  Try `xxd your_file`, you see the `0a` bit is the new line.

Comment: @Alcott you can look at your files with a hex editor if you want to see exactly what bytes they contain. Also, a file with a newline at the end would have a greater file size, so `ls` will also tell you they're not equal.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, yes, there is `0a`, is it appended automatically by vim for each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see in comment, there is a new line:

```
ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
float f;
ifs >> f;
char c;
ifs.get( c ); // this will get '\n'
```

Even so, the `EOF` still won't set.... Read the paragraph you quoted again:

> The function returns true if the eofbit stream's error flag has been
>   **set by a previous i/o operation**. This flag is set by all standard
>   input operations when the End Of File is reached in the sequence
>   associated with the stream.

To get the `eof` bit set, you have to read PASS the eof. You can use `peek()` to do it if you want.

```
ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
float f;
ifs >> f;
char c;
ifs.get( c ); // this will get '\n'
ifs.eof();  // this is false;
ifs.peek();
ifs.eof(); // this is true
```

See also: [istream::peek curious behavior wrt. EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763720/istreampeek-curious-behavior-wrt-eof)

Answer (score 2):

The vim is going to add a new line at the end of the file. That is why EOF is not reached.

Comment: a newline appended? Does it mean, if I `:set nu`, it should be `2` lines in there?

Comment: @Alcott no, that means that the EOF is in the next line (not in the line where the number is)

Comment: @Alcott, no. it means you have "set endofline" in vim (default is on). This append a NL at the end of file. Do a `:help eol`

Comment: @Alcott: Actually, as far as I understand the Unix convention for text files is that every line has to end with a newline character. That is, a file that doesn't end with `\n` technically isn't a valid text file. Since the `\n` is part of the line it ends, it doesn't increase the line count. Rather, `testcase1.txt` is technically incorrect. I also just tested with `wc`, and it reports *zero* lines if no newline character is present.